# Tests from another class are started before the execution of all the tests from the first class

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, vstest

During my testing using VSTest I have run into an issue, when the engine starts executing unit tests from a different test class before finishing the executing of all tests in the first class.

This is problematic because the the class cleanup have to be executed before moving to another class - there is static code that has to be called.

The tests are not executed in parallel.

Can anybody help?

Edit: This situation arises only in VS.NET during the debugging of the tests.

Comment: Could you please share your code and command to run the tests?

Comment: Your unit tests should not be dependent on outside resources like static code or global state in static objects. If this is what you are experiencing, then you should consider transforming your static code into instances that can be injected for your tests. If it can break your tests because you have no control over when it is used then it will break your product for the same reasons.

Comment: @MikeLimaSierra Yeah, I completely am aware of that, but this is a legacy code.

Comment: If that is the case and your tests are not executed in parallel then the tests are probably not executed one test class at a time. a quick solution would be to clean up after every test method to make sure it doesn't matter which test method is touched next.

Comment: I know that the tests are not perfect and the solution I am using otherwise is as suggested by @MikeLimaSierra - set up before the test method and clean up afterwards. That works, but the test are slow.

Comment: It looks like `ClassCleanup` is not called after all tests of the class are executed, but at the of the whole execuition https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx/issues/580.